# How to make Ajax send JSON to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am working on a webpage that needs to store data on the server in a .json file.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**Javascript code:**

```
// variable j = our json
var j;
function loadDoc(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            j = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","things.json",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
loadDoc();
function rewrite(){
    var xhr;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...  
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older  
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }  
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){

        };
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "write.php", true);
    xhr.send("data=" + j);
};
```

**The PHP file:**

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];  
file_put_contents('things.json', $data);
?>
```

Note, in other parts of my code the `j` variable is changed.

**My problem is that after the PHP script is making the JSON file blank. Am I doing anything wrong? Is php receiving the JSON properly? If so, how can I fix that?**

Cheers!

*If you vote down, please tell me why.*

Comment: How / where are you calling your `rewrite()` function and are you sure your asynchronous `loadDoc()` function has finished before that?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `j` when you're rewriting the file? It's a global so you have to be careful with that...

Comment: @jeroen The `loadDoc` function is declared first.

Comment: @gfish3000 The value of `j` is already established and correct.

Comment: Try to write the output into a different file - although it'll probably be empty, too.  Logically that means the data isn't available for the write.php script.  So it was either lost, or never been there.  Potential reasons I can think of: too big for your post size (check logs) or the $_POST is not filled or maybe the value is lost during a redirect or something.  I can't really think of more reasons right now, but you can probably look up something from here...but definitely check the access logs to see if things are happening in the order and the way they should.

Answer (score 0):

To POST data like an HTML form, add an HTTP header with setRequestHeader(). ([w3school page](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp))
so it must be : 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");